# Django migration fails to remove field

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I'm using Python 3.8.4, Django 2.2.3, SQLite 3.32.3.

When I run `python manage.py makemigrations`, Django creates a migration file containing the following operation, among others which execute successfully).

```
migrations.RemoveField(
    model_name='essayrequirement',
    name='program',
),
```

The `program` field's declaration before it is removed is as follows:

```
program = models.ForeignKey(UndergraduateProgram, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="essay_set", null=True, blank=True)
```

However, when I try to run the migration (`python manage.py migrate`), I get the error `django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: NewEssayRequirement has no field named 'program'`. (It seems NewEssayRequirement is a temporary table created in the course of applying the migration, which should replace the EssayRequirement table before the migration is complete.)

Poking around in the SQLite database itself *before* applying the migration confirms that the `program` field did in fact exist -- the column for it exists. In addition, I've tried removing this operation from the migration, and of course the next call to `makemigrations` brings it back. The same error occurs when `migrate`ing in this case.

Interestingly enough, there was another field called `non_undergrad_program` on the same model, differing only in where the ForeignKey points to. The migration in question also removes this field, but for some reason does so successfully:

```
migrations.RemoveField(
    model_name='essayrequirement',
    name='non_undergrad_program',
),
```

I've been stuck on this issue for a while, as it more or less breaks the migrations in our app moving forward. I can't even find a way to ignore the operation, and proceed forward ignoring that column's existence.

Comment: Please show the model before and after creating the migration, the full migration file, and the full traceback of the error

Comment: @Alasdair I figured out my issue while in the middle of doing that... whoops. Issue is resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was due to a uniqueness constraint on the field I had deleted, which I had overlooked:

```
class Meta:
    constraints = [
        models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['program', 'index'], name='unique_essay')
    ]
```

This constraint was the source of the `FieldDoesNotExist` exception. The issue was resolved by adjusting the constraint list and remaking migrations, then adding those generated operations to the problematic migrations file.